How to Run AWS lambda code parallel with SNS to SQS architecture
I have a problem. Let's say there's an external system, and an AWS Lambda function retrieves data from this system, converts it to a CSV, stores it on S3, and triggers an SNS event. This event then sends a message to an SQS queue. Another Lambda function (let's call it Lambda2) performs a costly task on the data stored in S3.
Here's the issue: The SQS batch size is set to 1, and there are multiple messages in the SQS queue. I need a way to run the same Lambda function in parallel if the previous instance of the same Lambda is not done, given the new Lambda concurrency limits. How can I achieve this?
I need a way to run the same Lambda function in parallel if the previous instance of the same Lambda is not done, given the new Lambda concurrency limits. How can I achieve this?

The default behaviour of AWS Lambda is to run multiple instances of the same function in parallel.  Are you saying that Lambda #2 is not running multiple instances in parallel? Have you set a Reserved Concurrency on it?

"I need a way to run the same Lambda function in parallel if the previous instance of the same Lambda is not done, given the new Lambda concurrency limits." You need to explain in much more detail what you are saying in that sentence. What "new" Lambda concurrency limits? What do you mean by "if the previous instance of the same Lambda is not done"?

You need to set "MaximumConcurrency" for the lambda(lambda 2 in your case) function to control maximum number of concurrent executions. As of now the value range is between 2-100, which specifies how many maximum concurrent executions the Lambda Function can have.

For more details visit https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-maximum-concurrency-of-aws-lambda-functions-when-using-amazon-sqs-as-an-event-source/

